# Is CERT record deprecated in DNS?

Tags: ssl, dns

I have a task which can be implemented via CERT records in DNS. (There is also an alternative method, but anyway)

I've been looking for DNS services that support CERT records but it appears that no one, including GoDaddy, supports it.

My questions are:

- Is it deprecated?
- If it isn't why commercial systems don't support it?
- Is there any system that support it? If yes, can you share the link?

**EDIT**

My search for the state of CERT records didn't give any results

Comment: Those who are voting for close, could you comment the reason?

Comment: Clicking on the `close(3)` button shows that there are 3 votes to close as off topic.

Comment: https://help.dyn.com/zone-records/#(CERT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like DynDNS supports CERT - http://dyn.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, CERT is not deprecated.  Dyn supports it with their Managed Express offering.